# T-SQL recursive update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What query should I use to update Total and Total_previous columns when I update Income or Outcome value for account. Mind that record are sorted by Posting_DataTime column and Transaction_ID is not sorted.

| Account No | Transaction_ID | Posting_DataTime | Income | Outcome | Total | Total_previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 11111111 | 2021-12-01 00:00 | 100 | null | 100 | null |
| 001 | 11112331 | 2021-12-04 04:00 | 10 | null | 110 | 100 |
| 021 | 11111031 | 2021-12-04 04:23 | 1200 | null | 2000 | 800 |
| 001 | 11111231 | 2021-12-08 07:44 | null | 40 | 70 | 110 |
| 001 | 00011231 | 2021-12-20 11:59 | 200 | null | 270 | 70 |

If I update Income value from 10 to 50 for 11112331 (Transaction_ID) then next rows for that account (001) should look like that

| Account No | Transaction_ID | Posting_DataTime | Income | Outcome | Total | Total_previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 11111111 | 2021-12-01 00:00 | 100 | null | 100 | null |
| 001 | 11112331 | 2021-12-04 04:00 | 50 | null | 150 | 100 |
| 021 | 11111031 | 2021-12-04 04:23 | 1200 | null | 2000 | 800 |
| 001 | 11111231 | 2021-12-08 07:44 | null | 40 | 110 | 150 |
| 001 | 00011231 | 2021-12-20 11:59 | 200 | null | 310 | 110 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you wish to add up (income - outcome) ordered by the posting_datatime by account_no. A better option instead of updating would be to have this as a "view" instead of updating each time there is a change.

```
    create table t(account_no varchar(10),trans_id varchar(1000),posting_datatime datetime,Income int, Outcome int);

    insert
      into t
    select '001','11111111','2021-12-01 00:00',100  ,null union all
    select '001','11112331','2021-12-04 04:00',10   ,null union all
    select '021','11111031','2021-12-04 04:23',1200 ,null union all
    select '001','11111231','2021-12-08 07:44',null ,40  union all
    select '001','00011231','2021-12-20 11:59',200  ,null;

    select account_no
           ,trans_id
           ,posting_datatime
           ,income
           ,outcome
           ,sum(isnull(income,0)-isnull(outcome,0)) 
               over(partition by account_no order by posting_datatime) as total
           ,sum(isnull(income,0)-isnull(outcome,0)) 
               over(partition by account_no order by posting_datatime)
                 -(isnull(income,0)-isnull(outcome,0))as total_prev
      from t
    order by posting_datatime;
```

| account_no | trans_id | posting_datatime | income | outcome | total | total_prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 11111111 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 100 | (null) | 100 | 0 |
| 001 | 11112331 | 2021-12-04 04:00:00.000 | 10 | (null) | 110 | 100 |
| 021 | 11111031 | 2021-12-04 04:23:00.000 | 1200 | (null) | 1200 | 0 |
| 001 | 11111231 | 2021-12-08 07:44:00.000 | (null) | 40 | 70 | 110 |
| 001 | 00011231 | 2021-12-20 11:59:00.000 | 200 | (null) | 270 | 70 |

link
https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/e86a41327cd213441797c775652f9a69/

Comment: You should add `ROWS UNOUNDED PRECEDING` to the `OVER` in case of duplicate dates. It's also faster